# Stripe web hooks could not be configured automatically

Tags: magento2, stripe

Even after running the command shown in the message below that admin page shows, it didn't disappear. Please suggest what else can I try?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that, than the message disappears, but I comes back after a while.
on Stripe side everything looks fine, no errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this in your stripe account .. then run the command
https://dashboard.stripe.com/webhooks